# HttpRequest and POST

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I keep getting one of the following error messages :

```
"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."  
               OR
"System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse."
```

Here is the code I'm running :

```
        StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
        bld.Append("contractId=");
        bld.Append(ctrId);
        bld.Append("&companyIds=");
        bld.Append("'" + company1+ ", " + company2+ "'");

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
            .Create(secureServiceUrl + "SetContractCompanyLinks");
        req.Credentials = service.Credentials;
        //req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = bld.Length;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        var encodedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bld.ToString());
        writer.Write(encodedData);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        var resp = req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Something must be wrong/missing in your request.  Have you checked the application log for errors?

Comment: yes, I checked it but there's nothing that appears, maybe I didn't configure it well. I'll check again.

Comment: This may not be the cause of the 400 response, but you should URLEncode the `ctrId` and `"'" + company1+ ", " + company2+ "'"`

Comment: now I'm getting the exception : System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A couple things that are "off":

**Write directly to your writer**
There shouldn't be a reason to call GetBytes(). The StreamWriter is perfectly capable of writing a string to the stream:

```
writer.Write(bld.ToString());
```

**Use the using() {} pattern around your StreamWriter**

This will ensure proper disposal of the writer object.

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
{
   writer.Write(bld.ToString());
}
```

**You don't need to explicitly set the content length**
Leave it alone, the framework will set it for you based on what you write to the request stream.

**If you need to be explicit about using ASCII, set the charset in the Content-Type header**

```
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ASCII";
```

You should also specify the encoding when instantiating your StreamWriter:

```
new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
```

Comment: after correcting the code,I still get a bad request exception stating that there was an error in the query syntax

Comment: Can you get fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and post the Raw content of your request to your question?

Answer (score 3):

```
    req.ContentLength = bld.Length;
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    var encodedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bld.ToString());
    writer.Write(encodedData);
```

You are not writing what you say you are going to be writing- you write the *ASCII encoded* bytes not your original byte array - the `ContentLength` has to match the number of bytes you write. Instead do:

```
    var encodedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bld.ToString());
    req.ContentLength = encodedData.Length;
```

Comment: I'm sure this is good advice, however, note I've come here with the same error as OP but my code does do exactly what this answer suggests already ie takes the length of the encoded bytes and sets that on the ContentLength - but I still get " You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse". It's intermittent, though... I've had this error come in once after literally hundreds of users call the same code many times per day without ever having a problem.