# Out of Memory Exception - Reading large text file for HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, streamreader

I am trying to read 500 MB text file to send it contents through HttpWebRequest. According to my requirement, I cannot send the data in chunks. Code is as follows :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    postData = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
{
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Reading such large file gives me out of memory exception. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Why can't you send it in chunks? And what exactly does that mean? Do you mean you can't use [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) or something else?

Comment: @svick: What I mean is that URL to which I am sending data.. should generate only one response.. which is equivalent to one job. So I want the sent data to be taken as one job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be encountering [this documented issue with `HttpWebRequest`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573). Per the KB article, try setting the `HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering` property to `false`.

Comment: Tried your suggestions. Works good..thanks. However, now I get an error while reading the response from the server. Gives me System.Net.ProtocolViolationException error : "You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream 
before calling [Begin]GetResponse" error.

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer here will work for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124797/httprequest-and-post

Answer (score 1):

All files are transferred in chunks - that's what an ethernet packet is; it's a single chunk of data.  I would wager that the requirement really means "this file must be transferred in a single web service call."

Assuming that's the case, you'd read the data from disk into a 64KB buffer, and then write the buffer to the request.

```
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        int count = reader.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        if (count < BUFFER_SIZE) break;
    }
}
dataStream.Close();
```

Comment: I basically did not want to generate more than one response from the server. I guess FileStream or buffer should solve the problem for large files...

Comment: Correct, buffering won't cause "more than one response from the server", and it will ensure that your call can succeed even if the size of the file increases past the amount of memory you have available.