# Load large image with memory efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, image, memory

I am using .NET4.5, Windows Forms and C#.

I am loading an image onto a button using:

```
theButton.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("file.png");
```

The issue is that my button is 128x128 and the image is 4000x8000. The line above consumes very large amounts of memory because file.png is so large.

Does anyone know of a technique I can use to reduce this memory footprint? I am thinking of some function like this:

```
Image.FromFile(file,width,height);
```

Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: I would probably load the image, resize it, dispose the original and use the resized one. If you still sue the same image, try to cache it somewhere

Comment: Ondra; this sounds like an elegant solution. Can you advise me on how I could dispose of the original image? Is this even possible with .NET?

Comment: MSRS was faster than me :) See his answer bellow

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works. It's quite simple to resize the image and then display it on button.

But, I don't think that the above code maintains the aspect ratio of the image.

It's quite simple to resize the image with aspect ratio; and then display it on button.
Below is the sample code helps you to resize the image by maintaining the aspect ratio.
You can define a new class or implement the "ResizeImage" method in an existing class. Whichever is comfortable to you.

```
public class ImageManipulation
{
    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap originalBitmap, int newWidth, int maxHeight, bool onlyResizeIfWider)
    {
        if (onlyResizeIfWider)
        {
            if (originalBitmap.Width <= newWidth)
            {
                newWidth = originalBitmap.Width;
            }
        }

        int newHeight = originalBitmap.Height * newWidth / originalBitmap.Width;
        if (newHeight > maxHeight)
        {
            // Resize with height instead
            newWidth = originalBitmap.Width * maxHeight / originalBitmap.Height;
            newHeight = maxHeight;
        }

        var alteredImage = new Bitmap(originalBitmap, new Size(newWidth, newHeight));
        alteredImage.SetResolution(72, 72);
        return alteredImage;
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
private void DisplayPhoto()
{
    // make sure the file is JPEG or GIF
                System.IO.FileInfo testFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(myFile);

    // Create a new stream to load this photo into
                FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(myFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // Create a buffer to hold the stream of bytes
                photo = new byte[myFileStream.Length];
                // Read the bytes from this stream and put it into the image buffer
                myStream.Read(photo, 0, (int)myFileStream.Length);
                // Close the stream
                myFileStream.Close();

    // Create a new MemoryStream and write all the information from
            // the byte array into the stream
            MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(photo, true);
            myStream.Write(photo, 0, photo.Length);

            // Use the MemoryStream to create the new BitMap object
            Bitmap FinalImage = new Bitmap(myStream);
            upicPhoto.Image = ImageManipulation.ResizeImage(
                                                FinalImage,
                                                upicPhoto.Width,
                                                upicPhoto.Height,
                                                true);


            // Close the stream
            myStream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best path here is to just resize the image, to 128x128.
An image that large is always going to take up a lot of memory, no matter what you do with it.

This will also allow you to make the image something that will look good at that size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the problem is that the source file is selected by the user so I am not able to resize if beforehand. I have used your solution for other scenarios where the images are in my control, and this works great, but not in my current situation..

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a general problem, AFAIK you have few possibilities

1. Compress image before uploading , in real world this will not work.
2. Put a check on size and dimensions of image, in real world it works, even linkedin, facebook they won't allow us to upload images above there specified dimensions.
3. Use buffering, this is cleanest way you can do in .net
4. Use some third party plugins or development enviornment, I have done it in Silverlight

Comment: Thanks Nipun, do you have any more information on point 3? The other solutions are not viable options for me at the moment.

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640844/out-of-memory-exception-reading-large-text-file-for-httpwebrequest