# Error while reading response from HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, filestream, httpwebresponse

I am trying to send contents of 1GB text file over the network. I modified the  [suggested code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573)  for basic authentication and kept it as follows :

```
        WRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);

        WRequest.Credentials = Credentials;
        WRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

        WRequest.ContentType = "text/plain"; 
        WRequest.Method = "POST";
        WRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        WRequest.Timeout = 10000;

        FileStream ReadIn = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        ReadIn.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
        WRequest.ContentLength = ReadIn.Length; 
        Byte[] FileData = new Byte[ReadIn.Length]; 
        int DataRead = 0;
        Stream tempStream = WRequest.GetRequestStream();
        do
        {
            DataRead = ReadIn.Read(FileData, 0, 2048);
            if (DataRead > 0) 
            {
                tempStream.Write(FileData, 0, DataRead);
                Array.Clear(FileData, 0, 2048); 
            }
        } while (DataRead > 0);


        // The response
        WResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WRequest.GetResponse();
```

However, now it gives me System.Net.ProtocolViolationException error : "You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse". I checked [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) ... and found from debugging that the contentlength for WRequest is not -1. What else could be going wrong ? How should I get the response ?

**Update** :
The code which worked for small files is as followed :

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = Credentials;


        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
                postData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "text/plain";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        // The response
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
             responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Comment: And what stops you from setting this value in a header in an explicit way?

Comment: @WiktorZychla : I really at loss ... as how to do this. I don't understand what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is the URL https by any chance?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: URL is not https...I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124797/httprequest-and-post post. When I was working with small files I used the Encoding.UTF8 to get the bytes to be read. I was wondering could that be a problem ? How do I ensure that I am reading it in right format ?

Comment: text/plain originally was 7-bit with SMTP.  I can't seem to find anything about bit-ness or UTF-ness w.r.t to http.  So, maybe that is the problem.  Have you tried another content type?

Comment: The "utf-ness" would be right in the data that you're reading.  If you read something that isn't text; maybe that would cause a protocol violation.

Comment: @PeterRitchie : I posted my code which worked alright for smaller files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you referenced says

> If the Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) Web server is configured to use Basic authentication, and you must set the HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering property to false, you must send a HEAD request to pre-authenticate the connection before you send the POST or PUT request.

EDIT - now with more clarification!

To restate the article, if you want to send a large file to a destination which requires basic authentication, you'll need to issue two separate requests. The key here is that you are setting `PreAuthenticate = true`. Read the statement literally -- by setting the property to `true`, you are saying that you will authenticate any requests that you make *before you actually attempt them!* The framework doesn't know how you want to accomplish this pre-authentication, so you need to perform that action yourself, by sending a `HEAD` request to the destination. Think of the `HEAD` HTTP method as being a prologue to the actual request - it describes (or requests information about) a particular resource.

So the process goes like this:

1. Make a HEAD request to `http://someurl/aresource` containing the credentials you want to use when making future requests from this client to that server for the listed resource
2. The server will respond (ideally) with "OK - you may proceed. You're authenticated"
3. The server immediately regrets its' decision to allow the operation as it finds itself saving a very large file :-)

I don't see you making that HEAD request anywhere in the code you posted - if it's not already there, add this at the beginning of your code (snipped from the sample article ref in OP):

```
//preAuth the request
// You can add logic so that you only pre-authenticate the very first request.
// You should not have to pre-authenticate each request.
WRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
// Set the username and the password.
WRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
WRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
WRequest.UserAgent = "Upload Test";
WRequest.Method = "HEAD";
WRequest.Timeout = 10000;
WResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WRequest.GetResponse(); 
WResponse.Close();
// Make the real request.
```

Comment: I understand that I am not doing this... as this gives me error. Basically, my requirement is to read a 500MB - 1 GB file. This is why I am trying to use FileStream or buffer to read it. But I haven't been successful in doing that.

Comment: right - but the article states that you have to make a total of *2* calls. The first is the HEAD call, the second is the call that performs the desired action

Comment: Right.. I understand. The HEAD call gives me "Internal Server Error". Only POST works. So when I change the first call to POST. It goes through first call.. but the second call gives me "The request was aborted: The request was canceled." after few iterations of do-while loop.

Comment: I don't understand this... Is the URL to which I am sending data is not reading in chunks ? This is what I still don't get. There is one limitation though that my destination URL cannot accept more that 1.5 GB file.

Comment: yes, the URL you send the first request to is the same URL you want to upload the file to. Since your destination won't accept files > 1.5GB, you'll probably want to perform some checks on your file's length prior to initiating these calls

Comment: Thanks.. I think I get "The request was aborted:The request was canceled" probably because the my upload file format is incorrect. Because I tried for another small 1KB file, it went through.

Also, one more thing... somehow, HEAD doesn't work for me. I have to use POST in all my calls.